# How to integrate event logging with C# and Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, events, extentreports, selenium4

I am logging all the events in the **Selenium** project with **C#** and **NUnit** using `ThreadStatic` attribute because every test is created in a different thread. The problem I am facing is inside the `CreateDriver` method. The event is being opened in a new thread and now the `internalLog` variable in the `LoggingClass` is in a different thread. As a result, the variable is null. I am looking for a way to log the messages in the same **ExtentTest** as the other messages of the test.

Technology:

- C#
- Selenium
- NUnit
- ExtentReports

```
public class LoggingClass
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static ExtentTest internalLog;

    private void LogMessage(Status status, string message)
    {
        internalLog.Log(status, message);
    }
}

public class GlobalEnvironment
{
    // I initialize the log here
    public static ILog Logger => applicationLogger;
}

public class Driver
{
    public static IWebDriver CreateDriver()
    {       
        // I create the driver here and then I subscribe to the event for the console

        IJavaScriptEngine monitor = new JavaScriptEngine(driver);
        List<string> consoleMessages = new List<string>();
        monitor.JavaScriptConsoleApiCalled += (sender, e) =>
        {
            GlobalEnvironment.Logger.Info($"Log: {e.MessageContent}");
        };
        await monitor.StartEventMonitoring();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the ExtentTest variable. Instead of working with threads, now I have a dictionary with the full name of the tests where I save the logs based on the test name. It looks like this:

```
public class LoggingClass
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ExtentTest> internalLogs;

    private void LogMessage(Status status, string message)
    {
        ExtentTest result;
        if (internalLogs.TryGetValue(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName, out result)) 
        {
            result.Log(status, message);
        }        
    }
}
```